# Remove permission of information_schema table for particular user

Tags: mysql, database

Whenever I create any user then I don't want to show information_schema table to that user. 
Is it possible to remove permission of information_schema table for particular user ?

Comment: What is it about information_schema that you specifically don't want the user to see?  With limited permissions elsewhere in mysql, each user should only see relevant information there, based on the limited permissions on other database objects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,85251,85251

However, you can manage what a user sees by manipulating their administrative role

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html